# How to set the property of ManagedBean not lose value when rendering components in JSF (Prefer Not use SessionBean or use static variables)

Tags: jsp, jsf-2

As we all know, when we render a component of the JSF web application, we will lose property value. We have two solutions:

1. Set the ManagedBean type Session in face-config.xml
2. Set property Of Managed Bean static type. E.x:

   **Public static String txtName Ex.**

I want to find a way not used the second way (so many they will only web browser access to a single static variable) and not to use a SessionBean like the 1st way.

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the view scope. It's designed for exactly this purpose. Remembering the values responsible for the view state across ajax requests on the same view.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    // ...

}
```

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scop)

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion. Can I define ViewScoped in face-config.xml like this: 

<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>userBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.demo.bean.UserBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

Comment: Yes. How exactly does that fail for you? Or haven't you even tried it at all? In the future, please try before asking :)

Comment: I tried over 20 times and it's still failed. The property value has been save but so unfortunately, the popup didn't show. I will show my demo error few minutes later

Comment: Apparently you're (implicitly) recreating the view everytime. Some code in flavor of an SSCCE would definitely help to spot the cause of the problem :)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTvd1NrAjxU&feature=youtu.be

Here is my web bug when I want to render a popup using viewScope in managed Bean

Comment: It's a nice video, but you're merely demonstrating/confirming the bug which you've already described in the question. The video did not show the full code in its entirety, let along in an SSCCE flavor, but I saw in an occassion in the video that you were using the `binding` attribute. That won't work in combination with the view scope due to JSF issue 1492. Get rid of the `binding` attributes or look for alternate ways.

Comment: Oh thank you, I will try to make better videos in next time. I've change way to show popup, not use binding. But unfortunately it still bug :(, the bug is the same with the bug when i use binding. 
I will send you my project example soon :). I'm very glad to talk with you :)